# Awaiting lots of tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a set of `Task` (lots of them, around 400):

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = ...
```

I want to run them all at the same time and then wait for each one of them. I use this piece of code to run the tasks:

```
Task.Run(async () => { ... });
```

Each of the task will run asynchronous methods themselves and that is why I need the `async` keyword in the lambda. Among these nested tasks there is notoriously `HTTP` requests that are sent and `HTTP` responses that are received.

I tried two different ways to wait for all the tasks to complete:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

and

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    await task;
}
```

Which, a priori, look exactly the same to me (but of course they don't seem to be otherwise I would not post here in the first place...).

The first way makes the tasks run faster but there are tons of `A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll` and others like this in the output window. Moreover, some tasks are still in the `WaitingForActivation` state *after* the call to `await Task.WhenAll()`.

The second way is slower and it *looks like* the tasks are not running simultaneously (I receive the `HTTP` responses one by one, while the first way of waiting the tasks make them coming almost all at the same time). Also, I see no `first chance exception` at all in the output window when I use the `foreach` loop to wait for each task and no task has the `WaitingForActivation` state after the loop.

I understand the "best" way to wait for a set of task is to use `WhenAll()` (at least for readability) but why these two methods behave differently? How can I overcome this issue? Ideally I would want the tasks to run fast and be sure that everything ended (I have a `try` `catch` `finally` block in the lambda to handle server error and I did not forget the `if(httpClient != null) httpClient.Dispose()` in the `finally` before anyone asks...).

Any hints are welcome!

**EDIT**:

Okay I tried another thing. I added:

```
.ContinueWith(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("#### ENDED = " + index)));
```

To each task, `index` being the number of the `Task`.
When using the `foreach` loop, I get :

```
#### ENDED = 0
#### ENDED = 1
#### ENDED = 2
#### ENDED = 3
#### ENDED = 4
...
```

When using the `WhenAll()`, I get :

```
#### ENDED = 1
#### ENDED = 3
#### ENDED = 0
#### ENDED = 4
#### ENDED = 8
...
```

So using the `foreach` loop make all my tasks run synchronously... which maybe explains why I don't get any `First Chance Exception` in the output window since the system is not stressed by the algorithm at all.

**EDIT2:**

Sample code : http://pastebin.com/5bMWicD4

It uses a public service available here : http://timezonedb.com/

Comment: It didn't make them run synchronously (they were already running) but you got the results synchronously, and in the order you created them

Comment: The way in which you `await` a `Task` should not affect how is that that task executed. Is this really your code and not something like `foreach (var job in jobs) { await Task.Run(…); } `? Could you post a short, but complete sample code that demonstrates this?

Comment: @svick I added a sample code in my post :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two attempts are totally different.

The first attempt *awaits* for all tasks to complete and continues afterwards. It will throw only after all the tasks have completed. <s>The order of the results is indeterminate and will depend on which task finishes first</s>.

The second waits for each task *one by one*, in the order they were placed in the tasks array, which of course is not what you want and is rather slow. It will abort waiting with an exception if even one task fails. The results of the other tasks will be lost.

It's not EXACTLY like running the tasks synchronously, since some tasks will finish earlier than others, but you still have to check them all one at a time.

You should note here that `Task.WhenAll` doesn't block by itself. It returns a Task that finishes when all other tasks have finished. By calling `await Task.WhenAll` you await on that task's completion. You could check that task's status to see whether one or more subtasks failed or were cancelled, or process the results with a call to ContinueWith.

You could also call Task.WaitAll instead of `await Task.WhenAll` to block until all the tasks finish, or *at least one of them cancels or aborts*. This is somewhat similar to your second attempt, although it still avoids waiting on all tasks one by one.

The fact that you have a lot of exceptions has nothing to do with the way you await. There are limits to how many HTTP connections you can make to the same domain (ie address) at a time, there may be timeout errors (usually caused by the connection limit) or other network related problems.

The kind of exceptions you receive though, is affected by whether you call `await Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WaitAll`. [This post explains the issue](http://stiller.co.il/blog/2012/12/accessing-the-aggregateexception-with-await/), but in short, `Task.WaitAll` will collect all exceptions and throw an AggregateException while `await Task.WhenAll` will only return one of them.

By the way, what is the message you receive for the SocketException?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I get it right, the lambda in the `ContinueWith()` will only be executed when the task will be explicitely awaited but not when the task ends by itself? About the `First Chance Exception`, I don't get any message at all even if I surround the `await WhenAll()` call with a `try` `catch` block. Is there a way to know what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: “The results of the other tasks will be lost.” They will be “lost” even with `Task.WhenAll()`. If any `Task` faults, the returned `Task` is also faulted. But you can always access the original `Task`s.

Comment: “The order of the results is indeterminate and will depend on which task finishes first.” The documentation says otherwise: [“The `Result` of the returned task will be set to an array containing all of the results of the supplied tasks **in the same order as they were provided**.”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874.aspx)

Comment: Fixed the order. As for the exceptions, check the bottom of the answer and the link to Eran Stiller's post about it

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of your code has nothing to do with `await`. It is caused by the way you iterate the collection of `Task`s. Most LINQ methods are lazy, which means they actually execute their code only when you iterate them.

So, this code starts each `Task` only after the previous one completed:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    await task;
}
```

but this code starts all of them at once:

```
foreach (var task in tasks.ToList())
{
    await task;
}
```

And since `Task.WhenAll()` does the equivalent of `ToList()` internally, you're going to get the same behavior as the second snippet above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is still something I don't get, the fact that I used `Task.Run`, does not it automatically run the `Task`? I thought that the only way to create a `Task` and start it later was to use the constructor `new Task()` itself.

Comment: @RedPolygon Yes, but that code is in a lambda that's not executed immediately, it's executed only when you iterate the resulting sequence.